# Life Span of Android broadCastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I Have instance variables in my Android BroadCastReciver. The Receiver is defined through the manifest file.

for example something like this:

```
public class MyPhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String myString="string one";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

myString= "string two";
```

}

//and here is the manifest definition

```
<receiver android:name="mypackage.receivers.MyPhoneStateReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Now lets imagine i recieve the very first intent now the myString variable will be two. But on the next event i receive will my instance variable be remembered or does it start initialized with "string one".  So really what i am asking is is the broadcastReciever instantiated everytime a new event occurs or does it keep its state ?  Also if it can lose state what other then a reboot could make it lose state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...is the broadcastReciever instantiated everytime a new event occurs or does it keep its state ?

A new instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` class will be created for each broadcast it's registered to receive. Your `myString` variable will be initialized to `"string one"`, and will have that value at the start of each `onReceive()` execution.

> Also if it can lose state what other then a reboot could make it lose state ?

I'm not quite sure what you mean, here, but any non-`static` members will not retain state from instance to instance, just like any other Object class. `static` members may retain state between broadcasts, but you shouldn't rely on that, as your process can be killed at any time. Rather, use some form of persistent storage, such as `SharedPreferences`, or standard `File`s.

Comment: So would you agree that if im listening to two events:    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
               and  <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />  that there would be two instances of the broadcastReceiver created then ?

Comment: no, im asking will it be the same object instance for both events or different  objects ?